# passing params to nested TabNavigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have `StackNavigator` with nested `TabNavigator` in it and I am navigating to the `VisitUserPageNew` and getting the params in the first screen that is being rendered which is `UserPage` and it works. But then I am trying to pass the params to the nested `UserSection` and it returns `undefined`

this is the navigation call:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('VisitUserPageNew',{
  visitorProps: {
    visitorNickName:this.props.linkPublisherNickName,
    visitor:true
  }
})
```

these are my components:

```
class UserPage extends Component {
    visitorProps = this.props.navigation.getParam('visitorProps')

    render() {
        console.log(this.visitorProps) // return the object I need
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Text</Text>
                <View  style={{width:'100%',height:'100%',flex:1}}>
                    <UserSection
                        visitorProps={this.visitorProps}
                    />
                </View>    
            </View> 
        )
    }
} 

export default class UserLinks extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.visitorProps) // return undefined
        return <View/>;
    }
}

export default class UserBookmarks extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.visitorProps) // return undefined
        return <View/>;
    }
}
```

this is the routes structure:

```
export const UserSection = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    UserFeed: {
        screen: UserLinks,
    },
    Saved: {
        screen: UserBookmarks,
    },
})

export const UserPageNew = StackNavigator({
    UserSectionPage: {
        screen: UserPage
    },
    UserSection: {
        screen: UserSection
    },
})

export const Home = StackNavigator({
    Main: {
        screen: Main
    }, 
    VisitUserPageNew: {
        screen: UserPageNew
    },
})
```

so passing the params to the first screen works great. But when I want to keep passing those same params to the nested `UserSection` it fails. I tried as well to call `visitorProps = this.props.navigation.getParam('visitorProps')` inside `UserBookmarks` and `UserLinks` but the result was the same. I could not get those params.

Comment: `UserLinks` and `UserBookmarks` should return something, at least an empty `View`.

Comment: yeah it was for demonstration propose they do return complete component

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm in the same situation (Drawer->Stack->TabNavigator) and when navigating to the Stack with param xyz, I can't access it in the TabNavigator component via navigation.getParam('xyz').